# VS Code How to set args when running or debugging a C# program in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

The program I'm trying to run/debug w/ args is in `${workspaceFolder}/src/GradeBook/Program.cs`

It looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace GradeBook {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            String greeting = args.Length > 0 ? $"Hello {args[0]}!" : "Hello!";
            Console.WriteLine(greeting);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the VS Code sidebar

1. click the Debug icon
2. click `create a launch.json file`
3. select `C#`. `launch.json` is created and opened.
4. click `Add Configuration`
5. select `{} .NET: Launch Executable file (Console)`
6. remove `"preLaunchTask": "build",`
7. fill in the the `"program"` path
8. add args to `"args"`, e.g. `"Jose Ville"`

`launch.json` will look something like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/bin/Debug/net8.0/GradeBook.dll",
            "args": ["Jose Ville"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when you run or debug the program, `"Jose Ville"` is passed in as an arg and `"Hello Jose Ville!"` will be written to the console.